# How can I change the color of a specific letter without having space

Tags: html, css

I don't know how I can make, in html, a specific letter in a word in another color without having a space before the letter. Need help :(

`<p>
    <span style="color: red">exam</span>
    <span style="color: blue">ple</span>
</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply remove the line break between the two spans.

Like this:

```html
<p>
    <span style="color: red">exam</span><span style="color: blue">ple</span>
</p>
```